# Angular Array of objects, when splicing by index it always removes last element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have some controllers like this:

```
app.controller("zipController", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {
  $scope.zipCodes = [];
  $scope.addZipCode = function() {
    $scope.zipCodes.push({code: '', distance: '25mi'});
  }
  $scope.removeZipCode = function(index) {
    console.log(index, 'index removing');
    $scope.zipCodes.splice(index, 1);
  }
});

app.controller("zipCodeController", function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<label ng-click="addZipCodes=!addZipCodes; addZipCode();"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Target Zip Codes <small>(Cities)</small></label>
<span ng-if="addZipCodes" style="white-space: normal;">
    <span ng-repeat="code in zipCodes track by $index" class="zipCodeInput" ng-controller="zipCodeController">
        <span class="zipCodeText">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" ng-model="zipCode" class="zipCode">
        </span>
        <span class="zipCodeSelect">
            <select ng-model="zipCodeDistance" ng-value="code.distance" class="zipCodeDistance">
                <option value="25mi">25 miles</option>
                <option value="50mi">50 miles</option>
                <option value="100mi">100 miles</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="zipCodeRemove">
            {{$index}}
            <a ng-click="removeZipCode($index)">x</a>
        </span>
    </span>
    <label ng-click="addZipCode();" class="addZipCode"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</label>
</span>
```

When I call the `removeZipCode($index)` function it has the correct index, however it always removes the last `$scope.zipCodes` from the array, not the correct zip code index.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you please create a working snippet/JSFiddle that reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Is it returning the correct index in the console.log line?

Comment: @epascarello Yes it is returning the correct index

Comment: This is caused by the use of `track by $index`

Comment: @devqon What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce in a fiddle? I created this one: https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/4/

Answer (score 1):

Remove "track by $index". it will work.

Comment: I created this fiddle that replicates the above structure, yet it does work with track by $index. How do you explain that? (https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/4/)

Answer (score 1):

you could use this

ng-repeat="(index,value) in array"

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-model` directives inside the `ng-repeat` are breaking the rule: **always have a dot "`.`" in your ng-models**

```
<span ng-if="addZipCodes" style="white-space: normal;">
    <span ng-repeat="item in zipCodes track by $index" class="zipCodeInput" ng-controller="zipCodeController">
        <span class="zipCodeText">
            <!-- REMOVE 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" ng-model="zipCode" class="zipCode">
            -->
            <!-- always have a dot in your ng-model -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" ng-model="item.code" class="zipCode">
        </span>
        <span class="zipCodeSelect">
            <!-- REMOVE
            <select ng-model="zipCodeDistance" ng-value="code.distance" class="zipCodeDistance">
            -->
            <!-- always have a dot in your ng-model -->
            <select ng-model="item.distance" ng-value="item.distance" class="zipCodeDistance">
                <option value="25mi">25 miles</option>
                <option value="50mi">50 miles</option>
                <option value="100mi">100 miles</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="zipCodeRemove">
            {{$index}}
            <a ng-click="removeZipCode($index)">x</a>
        </span>
    </span>
    <label ng-click="addZipCode();" class="addZipCode"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</label>
</span>
```

Because the `ng-repeat` directive creates a child scope for each item, when an `ng-model` directive omits a dot `.`, the model modifies items on the child scope and not the parent scope.

For more information, see [AngularJS Wiki - The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6tg87kq/)